# if statements, with x^2 possbilities, matching to a response, optional fields

Tags: php, if-statement, matching

If someone can think of a better name for the question, please make an edit :)

I have four fields, and all of them are optional, working in a PHP environment, although this question could relate to any language.

If they are set, they are sent to the server and a response is made.  I need to match the response ID with the field.

Fields:
A
B
C
D

Response Array: 0, 1, 2, 3

If all are set, it's easy. I can match them as is, A0, B1, C2, D3.  If only C and D are set, I get C0, D1.  If A, B, and D, are set, it's A0, B1, D2.

To code this, I would have to do:

```
if($a, $b, $c, $d) { $a = $response[0]; $b = $response[1]; $c = $response[2]; $d = $response[3]; }
elseif($a, $b, $d) { $a = $response[0]; $b = $response[1]; $d = $response[2]; }
elseif($a, $d) { $a = $response[0]; $d = $response[1]; }
```

etc etc for each possiblity, which is 16.  If I had 8 fields, there would be 64 if statements.

Is there a way to match the fields set to the response array without having to write x^2 if statements?

Thanks so much, please let me know if you need me to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Get your `$a`, `$b` etc. thingies in an array somehow; I suppose they're originally submitted as an array. So let's suppose you have an array like:

```
$letters = array('a', 'c');
```

Then simply:

```
$result = array_combine($letters, array_slice($response, 0, count($letters)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop to iterate over your `fileds` and an outer loop to iterate (2^n) no of times.

After dry running, i write the code which goes like this:

```
$fields = array("A","B","C","D".....m values)
$response_array_size = sizeof($fields) //size

for ($i = 0; $i < pow(2,$response_array_size); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0, $k = 0; j < $response_array-size; $j++) {
        if (isset( $fields[$j] ) {
           $set_fields[$k] = $response[$j];
           $k++;
        }
    /* do whatever with set_fileds
       set_fileds contains only the fields which were set
    */ 
    }
}
```

*Time Complexity*: n^2